# Python script to snap selected object to cursor

Tags: python, scripting, snapping

anyone know python script for Object>Snap>Selection to Cursor?
(Assuming I have the object selected)

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Just select the object and set it location to (0.0,0.0,0.0)

```
bpy.data.objects["name"].location = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
```

Comment: (0.0,0.0,0.0) is the center of the scene. The 3d Cursor is a different thing. There is an operator for snapping objects to the location of the 3d Cursor: `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor()` See [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20view3d%20snap_selected_to_cursor#bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor)